# sequence of series-Dirichlet Criterion

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have to check if this series : $\sum \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$ converge..
Can I do this,using the Dirichlet Criterion?I thought that I could let $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_{n}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ and apply the criterion.Is this possible?

Comment: No, that sum of $\;b_n\;$ isn't bounded...

Comment: I understand.....thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion: multiply numerator and denominator by $$\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt n$$

If you do this, you'll get $$\dfrac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt n)} \lt \dfrac 1{2n^{3/2}}\lt \dfrac 1{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: Very nice, but the OP says he wants to use Dirichlet's Test. +1

Comment: I couldn't resist posting anyway, @DonAntonio!

Comment: I see, @amWhy...and I don't think Dirichlet helps here.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: Ok...I got it...thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, evinda!